# non block read failed on stdout for python

Tags: python, subprocess, nonblocking

i want to be able to use the pdb as a subprocess, input the debug operator, and get its output. and I found the fcntl may help, but to my surprise, it work for other program like gdb, but when the cmd is "python", or ["python", "-m", "pdb", "computer.py"], this will not work.

I replace the cmd to 'gdb' or other program, it all works with fcntl.
but only failed when the cmd is 'python' related.

Popen(['python', '-m', 'pdb', 'computer.py'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, shell = False)

flags = fcntl(p.stdout.fileno(), F_GETFL)
fcntl(p.stdout.fileno(), F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK)

the expected result is i can get stdout correctly.

Answer (score 0):

plus "-u" argument. 
-u     : unbuffered binary stdout and stderr; also PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x
         see man page for details on internal buffering relating to '-u'